# How to add timing while display loading image on page load?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create display loading image on page load and the back screen should hide and only loading image should appear for at least 10 mins.

Added to display loading icon :

CSS:

```
#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 240px;
    z-index: 100;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
    <img id="loading-image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/img/loadingImg.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
<button type="submit" value="" class="btninstall btn-primary" onclick="showLoading()">INITIATE</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showLoading() {  
    var message = "Your Request has been Initiated, You may close the browser and continue your work.Once the Application Installed, it will appear in your Program List."+"\n"+"You can also check the status of your install progress on the Status Tab.";
    alert(message);     
    // $("#loading").fadeOut(5000) ;  
    $('#loading').show();
    //alert(setTimeout(30));        
}
```

This is what I am trying, please correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".btninstall").on("click", function(){
    var message = "Your Request has been Initiated, You may close the browser and continue your work.Once the Application Installed, it will appear in your Program List."+"\n"+"You can also check the status of your install progress on the Status Tab.";
alert(message);
$("#loading").delay(5000).fadeOut();
$("#loading").show();
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Lht)

Answer (score 0):

To show the loading image, you have to handle $(window).load event, because loading should be shown after page is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('#loading').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: m using it still not working plz check my code nd tell me where m wrong

Comment: are you able to display a loading only?(without fadeout function)

Comment: yes for 1 sec only i want it to stay for 10 sec but this way m not able to do it and i also want the backscreen should become inactive that time.as other loading page